ag-grid react rowData not updating
I am using ag-grid react and trying to update the data using the api with: rowNode.setData()
but when I try to read the rowData its not changing...
my code:
  import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'; // AG Grid Component
  import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Mandatory CSS required by the grid
  import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css"; // Optional Theme applied to the grid
  import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
  import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';


  const GridExample = () => {
    // Row Data: The data to be displayed.
    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
      { make: "Tesla", model: "Model Y", price: 64950, electric: true, id: '1' },
      { make: "Ford", model: "F-Series", price: 33850, electric: false, id: '2' },
      { make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", price: 29600, electric: false, id: '3' },
    ]);

    // Column Definitions: Defines the columns to be displayed.
    const [colDefs, setColDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>([
      { field: "make", editable: true },
      { field: "model" },
      { field: "price", },
      { field: "electric" }
    ]);
    const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>()


    return (
      // wrapping container with theme & size
      <div
        className="ag-theme-quartz" // applying the grid theme
        style={{ height: 500 }} // the grid will fill the size of the parent container
      >
        <AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef}
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={colDefs}
          getRowId={({ data }) => data.id}
        />
        <button onClick={() => {
          console.log('rowData', rowData);
        }}>print data</button>

        <button onClick={() => {
          const rowNode = gridRef.current?.api.getRowNode('2')
          //This is the row update
          rowNode?.setData( { make: "Ford", model: "newModel", price: 33850, electric: false, id: '2' });
        }}>update data</button>
      </div>
    )
  }



  const App = () => {
    return <GridExample />
  }

  export default App

I took ag-grid's code example and added the rowId and the buttons.
So when I click the update data button, the data on the table will change, but then when I print the data it stayed as before.
I tried using the api.applyTransaction() and the rowNode.updateData() but its the same result...
for some reason the rowNode.setDataValue will update rowNode but I can't use it in my project because its no supporting objects.

your rowData variable stays the same as before. To print the data as the updated data, you need to get the data from the grid, and then print it

When I'm edit the grid with cell editor the row data is changing... How can I accomplish this with the setData function?

You should know that AG-Grid won't update your local state if the grid data is internally changed.
You should either use declarative approach (pass rowData prop and update the prop -> setRowData) or use imperative approach (use grid api object and set data manually)
You can also use grid events like rowDataUpdated to update your state

I ended up doing exactly that. I used the onGridPreDestroyed
